# Loop thru tar file and run commands on each file

Tags: shell-script

I have a process of extracting new code to my servers where the code is packaged in a tar file. Each file referenced in the tar is backed up to a specific directory. I'd like to automate this process by reading the tar and processing each file accordingly. How can I do this in a shell script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU tar you can use [--to-command option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html)

It will run your command for each file in tar archive and pipe file's contents to its stdin.

For instance, this will print sha1 hashes for all files in archive

```
tar -x -z -f archive.tar.gz --to-command 'echo $(sha1sum | cut -d  " " -f 1) $TAR_FILENAME'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
tar xvf foo.tar | perl -ne 'print $last;$last=$_;END{print $last}' | parallel process file
```

For security reasons it is recommended you use your package manager to
install. But if you cannot do that then you can use this 10 seconds
installation.

The 10 seconds installation will try to do a full installation; if
that fails, a personal installation; if that fails, a minimal
installation.

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

To learn more:

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.

Comment: This is nice but I'm looking for an out-of-the-box approach using a script,sed,awk, etc.

Comment: Both the perl onliner above and GNU Parallel are perl scripts: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel so they should fit your purpose just fine.